# Referencing Class Methods inside Class Variables

Tags: python

How do you reference class methods within class variables?

For example:

I have

```
class UU(object):

  map = {
    'username': get_username
  }

  @classmethod
  def get_username(cls):
    pass
```

However, `get_username` can't be found.

I tried `UU.get_username` but that does not appear to work.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `UU.get_username` "works", it just doesn't do anything. What is `map` supposed to do? It just lets you write something verbose like `UU.map['username']` as a reference to the class method. (Or it would, if `get_username` were defined yet, which it isn't.)

Comment: In another function, I want to pass in certain keys to the map and run the functions that correspond to the values. However, these functions can be stateless. The map could be taken out of the class, but it's largely there for readability.

Comment: I've added something to my answer about using `getattr`, which might be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because UU's methods are defined after the class variables - so `get_username` doesn't exist when you try to add it to the dictionary.

Try this:

```
class UU(object):

  @classmethod
  def get_username(cls):
    pass

UU.map = {
    'username': UU.get_username
  }
```

Judging by your comment on the question, you might find `getattr` useful.

Example:

```
method_name = "get_username"
method = getattr(UU, method_name)
method()
```

or just

```
getattr(UU, "get_username")()
```

No dictionary needed!

Answer (score 3):

The class body is executed just like a function is, and the local namespace is then turned into the class attributes.

As such normal naming order requirements apply; you cannot reference `get_username()` because it is *not yet defined*.

Moreover, you'd get the *unbound `classmethod` object* even if you moved the `map` definition down below the `get_username()` definition.

As such, you'd add the method to the mapping *after* creating the class:

```
class UU(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_username(cls):
        pass

UU.map = {
    'username': UU.get_username
}
```

Note that this means than from there on out `UU.map['username']` is using a `classmethod` bound to the `UU` class. You'll not get the version on a subclass if you have ever subclassed `UU` and provided an override of that method.

You'd have to jump through a lot more hoops to make this work for subclasses; you'd have to make `map` a [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) so you can bind class methods when looking up values in the mapping, not when defining the mapping:

```
class BindingMap(dict):
    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        return {k: v.__get__(instance, cls) if hasattr(v, '__get__') else v for k, v in self.items()}

class UU(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_username(cls):
        pass

    map = BindingMap({
        'username': get_username,
    })
```

The map will then produce bound class methods on demand, extending to subclasses:

```
>>> class BindingMap(dict):
...     def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
...         return {k: v.__get__(instance, cls) if hasattr(v, '__get__') else v for k, v in self.items()}
... 
>>> class UU(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def get_username(cls):
...         pass
...     map = BindingMap({
...         'username': get_username,
...     })
... 
>>> UU.map
{'username': <bound method type.get_username of <class '__main__.UU'>>}
>>> UU.map['username']
<bound method type.get_username of <class '__main__.UU'>>
>>> UU.map['username']()
>>> class UU(object):
...     @classmethod
...     def get_username(cls):
...         print('Username for class {}'.format(cls.__name__))
...     map = BindingMap({
...         'username': get_username,
...     })
... 
>>> UU.map
{'username': <bound method type.get_username of <class '__main__.UU'>>}
>>> UU.map['username']
<bound method type.get_username of <class '__main__.UU'>>
>>> UU.map['username']()
Username for class UU
>>> class Foo(UU):
...     pass
... 
>>> Foo.map
{'username': <bound method type.get_username of <class '__main__.Foo'>>}
>>> Foo.map['username']
<bound method type.get_username of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
>>> Foo.map['username']()
Username for class Foo
```

Comment: unubutu's code seems to disagree with "Moreover, you'd get the unbound classmethod object even if you moved the map definition down below the get_username() definition.", if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: nope, his code shows you are getting just the classmethod object, unbound. The bound method looks like `<bound method type.get_username of <class '__main__.UU'>>`.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: You run into [`TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11058686/190597) if you try calling the unbound classmethod using my code. It's not useful, so I deleted my answer.