# dict .get method goes to default even though key exists in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Please consider the following code

```
class A(object):
    cache = {}

    @classmethod
    def instance_by_id(cls, id_):
        cache = cls.cache
        if id_ in cache:
            print(f"id {id_} already in cache")
        instance = cache.get(id_, A(id_))
        cache[id_] = instance

    def __init__(self, id_):
        self._id = id_
        print(f"creating instance for {id_}")



def main():
    for n in [1, 1, 1, 1]:
        instance = A.instance_by_id(n)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Its output is

```
creating instance for 1
id 1 already in cache
creating instance for 1
id 1 already in cache
creating instance for 1
id 1 already in cache
creating instance for 1
```

I expected the output to be

```
creating instance for 1
id 1 already in cache
id 1 already in cache
id 1 already in cache
```

What's going on here?

Comment: In the line `cache.get(id_, A(id_))`,  `A(id_)` is evaluated **first**, only then `cache.get` is being called with `id_` and the already created instance as arguments.

Comment: You can try to use `lru_cache` as a class decorator and avoid all that logic. From a quick test I did it seems to behave as expected

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks! the cache decorator is REALLY nice, good to know! Is there a parameterized version of `cached_property`?

Comment: Mmm I guess just `@lru_cache` on methods.

Comment: @DeepSpace Looks like doing `@lru_cache` on a class makes `@classmethod`s not callable, as it [interferes with binding order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11058686/913098). Also, I couldn't find an easy on-disk caching, which I can do quite easily using above method with pickle. Good to know nontheless